# Django is not routing resource properly "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) main.7ec538f6.chunk.js:1"

Tags: reactjs, django

I was working on web development using Django for backend and react for frontend.
react build files are working properly but the same build file is not serving properly by Django.
when change debug == false media files are not serving and favicon is not fetched by Django.

Answer (score 0):

Because django user different settings for `static files` in production

> Serving static files in production. The basic outline of putting static files into production consists of two steps: run the collectstatic command when static files change, then arrange for the collected static files directory ( STATIC_ROOT ) to be moved to the static file server and served.

read the [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/deployment/#:%7E:text=Serving%20static%20files%20in%20production,static%20file%20server%20and%20served.) for it